# Using Perl's map with custom functions

Tags: perl, higher-order-functions

I have a Perl script that has (skipping many irrelevant lines)

```
use HTML::Entities;
my @keys = ('ID', 'first', 'last'); # data is not actually constant
my @encodedKeys = map(encode_entities, @keys);
```

which runs without error.  But when I try to access the values in the array, I get errors:

```
Use of uninitialized value $encodedKeys[0] in join or string at myfile.pl line 48.
```

If I remove the mapping the code works properly -- that is, the variables are not null or empty strings.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a good idiomatic way to do this?  (It's obviously trivial to do sequentially.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the code to work correctly as posted in the question, `encode_entities` needs to be prototyped. A quick glance at the [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.68/lib/HTML/Entities.pm) shows that this isn't the case.

The correct way to call it is:

```
my @encodedKeys = map { encode_entities( $_ ) } @keys;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `encode_entities` function does not use `$_` by default, so you need to pass it an argument.  Changing your `map` statement to the following will work:

```
my @encodedKeys = map {encode_entities $_} @keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `encode_entities` replaces HTML entities *in-place*, you may want to use `map` on a copy of `@keys`:

```
 my @encodedKeys = map encode_entities($_), @{[ @keys ]};
```

Otherwise, `foreach` is better suited for the task:

```
encode_entities($_) for @keys;
```